# Axes labeling and Centering of figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Code 1:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[view={110}{20},
                height = 4in,width=4in,
                axis lines=center,axis on top,
                no marks,axis equal,
                xlabel = $x$,
                xmin=-2.5,xmax=2.5,ymin=-2.5,ymax=2.5,zmin=-2.5,zmax=2.5,
                        enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
                \addplot3+[color = blue, thick, no markers,samples=250, samples y=0,domain=0:2*pi,variable=\t, decoration={
    markings,
    mark=between positions 0.01 and .999 step 2em with {\arrow [scale=1]{stealth}}
    }, postaction=decorate]({sin(\t r)},{sin(2*\t r)},{sin(3*\t r)});
                \addplot3+[color = red, thick,samples = 2, domain = 0:1, variable = \t, -stealth] ({sin(3 r) + \t*cos(3 r)}, {sin(6 r) + 2*cos(6 r)*\t}, {sin(9 r) + 3*cos(9 r)*\t});
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output 1:
[image]

Code 2:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[view={110}{20},
                height = 9in,width=9in,
                axis lines=center,axis on top,
                no marks,axis equal,
                xmin=-2.5,xmax=2.5,ymin=-2.5,ymax=2.5,zmin=-2.5,zmax=2.5,
                        enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
                \addplot3+[color = blue, thick, no markers,samples=250, samples y=0,domain=0:2*pi,variable=\t, decoration={
    markings,
    mark=between positions 0.01 and .999 step 2em with {\arrow [scale=1]{stealth}}
    }, postaction=decorate]({sin(\t r)},{sin(2*\t r)},{sin(3*\t r)});
                \addplot3+[color = red, thick,samples = 2, domain = 0:1, variable = \t, -stealth] ({sin(3 r) + \t*cos(3 r)}, {sin(6 r) + 2*cos(6 r)*\t}, {sin(9 r) + 3*cos(9 r)*\t});
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output 2:
[image]

For code 1, how come is the x-label not in the right position? How to get the label in the right position on the x-axis as well as for y and z on the respective axes? For code 2, when I set height = width = 9in, the figure is not centered anymore. How to center it?

Comment: The first problem disappears is you add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}` to the preamble of your document. As for the second problem, the plot is just too wide, so TeX will put it such that it does not overshoot to the left so it overshoots to the right and is thus no longer centered.

Comment: Actually, I figured out the solution for the second problem, which I forgot a while ago: `\adjustwidth`

Comment: Yes, but this rescales the fonts.

Comment: Hmmmm I have never seen the font be rescaled though. I have used it before and nothing happened to the fonts, unless I overlooked.